# Angularjs 1.4.4: Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, sockjs

I want to use SockJs to receive all the events published by stomp from the server side. I have created WebSocketController. It is initiated in app.js as

`.controller('webSocketController', webSocketController)`

WebSocketController.js

```
class WebSocketController {

  constructor($rootScope, $scope) {
   Object.assign(this, {$rootScope, $scope});
    this.onConnected = this.onConnected.bind(this);
    this.stompClient = '';
    let vm = this;

    setTimeout(function () {
            vm.connect();
    }, 2000);
  }

  onConnected(frame) {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', this.showMessage);
  }

  onError(error) {
      console.log("Could not connect to WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try again!");
      console.log("error: ", error);
  }

  connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    this.stompClient.connect({}, this.onConnected, this.onError);
  }

  showMessage(message) {
      console.log("message received: ",message);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshAccessPointList');
  }

  getStompClient() {
    return this.stompClient;
  }

}

var MyController = new WebSocketController();
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
export default MyController;
```

When showMessage() tries to broadcast the event received, it fails to find $rootScope. 
Console says : Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined at l (webSocket.controller.js?eaab:33)
Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After your class, **inject dependencies to your controller class** and **then to your module**.

```
export class WebSocketController {

  constructor($rootScope, $scope) {
   Object.assign(this, {$rootScope, $scope});
    this.onConnected = this.onConnected.bind(this);
    this.stompClient = '';
    let vm = this;

   ....
   ....
   ....


  getStompClient() {
    return this.stompClient;
  }

}
```

Now,

**Inject dependencies to your controller class:**

`WebSocketController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];`

**Inject controller dependency to your module:**

`angular.module('app').controller('WebSocketController', WebSocketController);`

Comment: Dependency injection for WebSocketController will be done in WebSocketController .js and Injection of controller dependency is done in app.js. How can I prioritize the order of injection?

Comment: instead of initializing new object, try exporting the class directly, or if not just add the module dependency in the same file, as I have said in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should setup $inject annotation before you create instance of the controller

```
WebSocketController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];
export class WebSocketController;
```

Also, i think you should not need to manually create instance of the WebSocketController.

```
someModule.controller('WebSocketController', WebSocketController);
```